# AWS API gateway and LAMBDA Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I hava a aws API which is connected to AWS-LAMBDA written in JAVA.in API Gateway inside of Integration response i pass some json string from context variable and 
like below

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
    "UserID":"$context.authorizer.claims.sub",
    "Identity":"$context.identity.cognitoIdentityId",
    "Account ID":"$context.identity.accountId",
    "UserID2":"$context.authorizer.claims.email"
}
```

but in my lambda function i try to read those values as below.

```
context.getLogger().log("Input or Query String"+ input);
```

the problem it's reading complete text but not in json format.it gives me a format likebelow.

```
Input or Query String{UserID=379fa501-0028-XXXX-a1c2-f0c54691b4d3, Identity=XX, Account ID=XX, UserID2=XXXXXXX@gmail.com}
```

How can i convert this in to json format..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON passed into the Java Lambda function by AWS will be a Map of the type `Map<String, Object>`. The logger class serialises the incoming object to a string, so when you look at the input in a log, it looks like a json string even though it's not.

Try this:

```
public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<Object, Object>{

    @Override
    public Object handleRequest(Object input, Context context) {
        Map<String, Object> mappedInput = (Map<String, Object>)input;
        context.getLogger().log("User ID: " + mappedInput.get("UserID"));
    }
```

You'll obviously want to use more type checking than I've included here.

Comment: Thank you sir.It's Amazing people help people that never seen.It works exactly like this.what if i have json object like {"Person": {"Name":"xxxx",Age:"xx"}}

Comment: Each incoming JSON object is passed in as a Map, so in your case the input map will contain an object with the key "Person". This object will in turn be a Map with a key "Name" and a key "Age".

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your string to a json the link below are some easy ways to do so.
http://www.java67.com/2016/10/3-ways-to-convert-string-to-json-object-in-java.html?m=1